# microk8s offline installation failed with timeout

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s

Followed the instruction from https://microk8s.io/docs/install-alternatives#heading--offline, with the virtual network interface.
On Ubuntu 20.04

Running the install command including --classic `sudo snap install microk8s_3021.snap --classic`

Getting an error

> error: cannot perform the following tasks:
>
> - Start snap "microk8s" (3021) services (systemctl command [start snap.microk8s.daemon-containerd.service] failed with exit status 1:
>   Job for snap.microk8s.daemon-containerd.service failed because a
>   timeout was exceeded. See "systemctl status
>   snap.microk8s.daemon-containerd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for
>   details.

Getting commnd not found when running `snap.microk8s.daemon-containerd.service`

Do not see any error of the microk8s using the journalctl -xe command

Any idea how to install microk8s in an offline environment

Answer (score 0):

Same message. While I ran the snap command, I had an independent process consuming CPU utilization. I killed this heavy process and tried snap again. No more timeout.

Comment: What is the output from:
`SNAPD_DEBUG=1 snap install microk8s --classic`